# Can't encode audio from PCM 16 bits encoding to G711-MLAW using MediaCodec?

Tags: encoding, android-mediacodec

I want to encode audio to G711-MLAW using MediaCodec. I listed the supported codecs, the result was as follows:

```
OMX.google.mp3.decoder
OMX.google.amrnb.decoder
OMX.google.amrwb.decoder
OMX.google.aac.decoder
OMX.google.g711.alaw.decoder
OMX.google.vorbis.decoder
OMX.google.opus.decoder
OMX.google.raw.decoder
OMX.google.aac.encoder
OMX.google.amrnb.encoder
OMX.google.amrwb.encoder
OMX.google.flac.encoder
OMX.google.gsm.decoder
OMX.google.mpeg4.decoder
OMX.google.h263.decoder
OMX.google.h264.decoder
OMX.google.hevc.decoder
OMX.google.vp8.decoder
OMX.google.vp9.decoder
OMX.google.h263.encoder
OMX.google.h264.encoder
OMX.google.mpeg4.encoder
OMX.google.vp8.encoder
```

I can't find OMX.google.g711.mlaw.ecoder!. How can encode using G711-MLAW? I tried using the MediaCodec codec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_AUDIO_G711_MLAW); but the result was unable to instantiate the codec G711-MLAW ? ho to encode audio using the G711-MLAW codec.